# More general better error bounds for partial sums of reciprocals of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102720/better-error-bounds-for-partial-sums-of-reciprocals-of-primes) Gerhard Paseman asks for explicit estimates on $E(k)$ in 
$$\sum_{ p \text{ prime,} p \leq k } 1/p  - \log{\log{k}} = B + E(k).$$

There are some nice answers, but my question is on the analogue in the prime ideal case; in particular, I am in the explicit form of the dependence on the number field.

Comment: See this mathOverflow question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21509/mertens-like-sum-in-arithmetic-progressions